# Want to trigger an event when user navigate from 3rd item to 4th item in the panorama

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, panorama-control

I need to trigger an event when the user reaches the third panorama item or navigate from 3rd item to 4th item. Is it possible to do in panorama. for example if the user raches the 3rd item and navigate to the 4th item.

a message box should display "you are navigating from 3 to 4".

kindly guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to selection changed in the xaml/codebehind:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.selectionchanged(v=vs.92).aspx

There's some example code here: http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=185